# How to implement methods differently depending on type in a generic class in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, console-application

I decided I'd try to make a basic class to handle matrices to learn more about the language.

I wanted to make the class able to handle matrices of different types (int, double, bool etc. but also non-numerical objects such as strings and even other class and struct types if possible). I don't plan on implementing all of the basic arithmetic that you would get with normal mathematical matrices like matrix addition and multiplication, but rather I'd like to use the matrices as a way of storing data in a grid pattern, sort of like what you would see in MatLab. Here is my matrix class thus far:

```
class Matrix<T>
{
    private readonly T[,] _elements;
    public readonly int Rows;
    public readonly int Cols;

    public T this[int i, int j]
    {
        get { return _elements[i, j]; }
        set { _elements[i, j] = value; }
    }

    public Matrix(int rows, int cols, T fill) //fill is a baseline default type that should populate the matrix
    {
        Rows = rows;
        Cols = cols;
        _elements = new T[rows, cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                _elements[i, j] = fill;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try //surrounded by try-catch in case a type conversion error occurs
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
            {
                sb.AppendLine();
                for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++)
                {
                    sb.Append(_elements[i, j] + "\t");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred.");
        }
    }
}
```

So, before you bash me for doing everything wrong and not following any code conventions, let's take a look at the Display method I've created in the class. Obviously, this method will be functional for basic types like integers, doubles, and strings because these types can be implicitly converted to strings and displayed on the console. Where it gets tricky is when we start making matrices that accept types of user-defined classes. Here is an example:

Let's say I have this simple Person class:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

I want to allow users of the `Matrix` class to be able to somehow change the implementation of the `Display` method depending on the type specified so that, well, for example, the following code will display a matrix of the People's names rather than attempting to display the type "Person" for each element:

```
Matrix<Person> people = new Matrix<Person>(4, 4, new Person("John", 56));
people.Display();
```

I've thought about possibly using an interface of some sort that forces any user-defined types to have their own implicit conversion to a string so that the Display function can display `personObject.Name`instead of trying to display the whole `personObject`, but I honestly have no idea what that would look like or if it is even possible, since that would mean that in order for basic types to work like `int` and `string` they would have to implement the interface as well, right?

Comment: "*So, before you bash me for doing everything wrong and not following any code conventions*" -- lucky you wrote this, we were all getting our pitch forks sharpened

Comment: If you *override* `ToString` in any user defined class, you are good to go, its any other T that might be the problem

Comment: Agree with TheGeneral. Sounds like this is what polymorphism is intended to solve. It would be more logical to call your Display method ToString, have it override ToString and call ToString on every element in the matrix.. but honestly, displaying the contents of a data storage container is Not Your Problem - Microsoft didn't provide a Display method on an array, they just provide a way for YOU to enumerate it and display it how you like.  Convention note: make publicly accessible properties, not fields :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a usage I would narrow *T* to ensure the type can be displayed. So any implementation is forced to provide the ability to display itself (w/o overriding ToString())

```
  public abstract class MatrixItemBase
   {
     public abstract string Display();
   }

  public class Matrix<T> where T : MatrixItemBase
   {
    public void Display()
     {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      try //surrounded by try-catch in case a type conversion error occurs
       {
        for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
         {
            sb.AppendLine();
            for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(_elements[i, j].Display());
            }
         }
         Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
       catch
       {
         Console.WriteLine("An error occurred.");
       }
     }
   }

class Person : MatrixItemBase
{
  public string Name;
  public int Age;

  public Person(string name, int age)
  {
    Name = name;
    Age = age;
  }

  public override string Display()
  {
    return Name; //or whatever
  }
}
```

or you could use an Interface instead of an abstract base class...

if you want to support structs and basic types also w/o control over the output you could remove the narrowing and add a condition to your Display Method, like

```
//inside your for loop
var e = _elements[i, j];
if (e is MatrixItemBase item)
  sb.AppendLine(item.Display());
else
  sb.AppendLine(e.ToString());
```

Comment: Ok so if I want it to support basic types as well, I'd have to remove T's requirement of being MatrixItemBase, which means people will still be able to pass in types that are not basic nor inherit from MatrixItemBase... Hmm, would be nice if there was a way to require a type to be of type MatrixItemBase OR basic type. Would it be best just to add an error somewhere, something like "Type not supported - Please Inherit MatrixItemBase" so that when someone tries to display a type that can't be converted into a string it gets thrown?

Comment: Agree, it would be nice if you could narrow generic type arguments to several types, but sadly it's not supported, AFAIK. Every class/struct has a string representation (fallback is the type name), so filtering it out would be hard. For an error message, like you describe, just leave the constraint to MatrixItemBase to get an exception thrown, or adapt the *else* in the if clause to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

The best solution for this would probably be to use abstract classes.

Also, it would be much better to override the `object.ToString()` method instead of creating your own `Display()` method.

```cs
using System.Text;

abstract class MatrixItemType
{
    public abstract override string ToString ();
}

class Matrix<T> where T : MatrixItemType
{
    private readonly T[,] _elements;
    public readonly int rows;
    public readonly int cols;

    public Matrix ( int rows , int cols , T fill )
    {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        _elements = new T[rows , cols];

        for ( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
            {
                _elements[i , j] = fill;
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString ()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try //surrounded by try-catch in case a type conversion error occurs
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
            {
                for ( int j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
                {
                    sb.Append(_elements[i , j].ToString() + "\t");
                }

                sb.AppendLine();
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

### Example

```cs
using System;

class Person : MatrixItemType
{
    public string name;
    public int age;

    public Person ( string name , int age )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public override string ToString ()
    {
        return $"{name} is {age} years old.";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main ()
    {
        Matrix<Person> people = new Matrix<Person>(4 , 4 , new Person("John" , 56));
        Console.Write(people.ToString());
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
John is 56 years old.   John is 56 years old.   John is 56 years old.   John is 56 years old.
John is 56 years old.   John is 56 years old.   John is 56 years old.   John is 56 years old.
John is 56 years old.   John is 56 years old.   John is 56 years old.   John is 56 years old.
John is 56 years old.   John is 56 years old.   John is 56 years old.   John is 56 years old.
```

## Extra

There are a few things you can improve on - mostly shorter code that does the same thing.

- [Expression body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator#expression-body-definition) for methods (requires C# 6/7)
- [Target-typed instantiation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator#constructor-invocation) - omit the type name, and just type `new()` (requires C# 9)
- Use [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) instead of fields.